# How do I label (or name) a disk?

Tags: disk

How do I label (or name) a disk? I can find all kinds of ways to label a partition, but I can find nothing on a label that I can set that applies to the entire physical disk.

I also need to read/write with software, python's (using pyudev maybe?) preferred.

thx, tom.c

Comment: There is no single *disk* scheme, though most systems use partition tables, there are multiple choices of tables that can exist. Most *labelling* is done at partition level, not device (disk) level so have you considered what you're asking, as to me it makes little sense (*given a mount/file-system can cross multiple drives thus a single drive having a label makes no sense at all; as device/drive isn't the usual division; not since 1970s anyway*)